# how to report the comparison of two samples means, accounting for covariates

Tags: r, t-test, ancova, reporting, predictor

I have two groups, patients & controls, and a dependent variable "performance".

I want to compare the means of the two groups, but after removing the effect of two confounding continuous variables: age & scholarity.

I've thought of two possible ways:

1) manually removing the effects, and performing a t-test:

```
lm1 = lm(performance ~ age + scholarity)
t.test(residuals(lm1) ~ group)
```

2) performing ANCOVA:

```
lm1 = lm(performance ~ age + scholarity + group)
Anova(lm1)
```

Since the p-values are almost exactly the same, I assume the two methods are equal, but my question is which is the best way to report my results. Specifically:

1. Should I plot data **after** having removed the covariates or before?
2. If "after" how do I get them on the original scale after having removed the covariates effect? (i.e. `residuals(lm1)` returns data centered on zero)
3. Which effect size should I report? Cohen's d or eta squared, or something else?
4. How do I compute confidence intervals?